# sed text replacement

Tags: linux

I have a text document file which contains thousands of lines. each line looks like below

```
141.132.86.86,53240,203.178.142.200,80,6,550,22425,1089,1630060,40,40,453,17,52,1496,1500,61,14,11578,220465,33191,11,5649,230153,23516,6356945,6356945,6356945,6356945,0,0,0,0,0,550,22425,1089,1630060,1,2,0,0,22012,43572,0
```

I am wondering if I can use sed to replace/change value of a specific column. (columns are separated by commas).

For example, if I need to change value of fourth and fifth column from 80 and 6 respectively into 1 and 2.

To be noted that value for different lines are different. I need to change the value of a specific column.

Thanks for your care in advance and appreciate your kindness.

Comment: What do you mean by "value for different lines are different"?

Answer (score 0):

With pure Bash

```sh
#!/bin/sh
IFS=, read -a ca < a.txt
ca[3]=1
ca[4]=2
IFS=, read cs <<< "${ca[*]}"
echo $cs > a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed:

```
sed 's/\(\(.*,\)\{3\}\)80,6,\(.*\)/\11,2,\3/g'
```

Awk isn't designed to edit things in-place. But it provide perfect support for field editing, you can use it anyway like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {OFS=","} {if($4 = 80) $4=1;if($5 = 6) $5=2;print}' input.txt > output.txt  && mv input.txt input.txt.old && mv output.txt input.txt
```